# How to pass driver path on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

```
IWebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver(" '+ Server.MapPath("~\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.2\\IEDriverServer.exe") +' ");
```

Driver Not Found Error? 
I am using ASP.NET, C#. Any Help..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
  private const string URL = "http://url";
    private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\PathTo\IEDriverServer";

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
        {
            InitialBrowserUrl = URL,
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
        };
        var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);
        driver.Navigate();
        driver.Close(); 
        driver.Quit(); 
    }
```

You have to include the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` and

```
OpenQA.Selenium.IE namespace
```

Comment: I got the exe file on server, how can i get the server location and pass it as a string to driver?